# Normal Distribution Approximations and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_{144}$ be a random sample from a population with mean $\mu  = 20$ and
variance $\sigma^2 = 64$.

(a) What is the approximate distribution of $\bar X$?

(b) Find $P( \bar{X} < 19)$.

(c) Find a constant $c$ such that $P(|\bar{X}-20| < c) = 0.95$

My attempt

(a) $\bar{X} \overset{\text{approx}}{\sim} N\left(20, \frac{64}{144}\right)$

(b) $P(Z<19)=P\left(Z<\dfrac{19-20}{2/3}\right) = P(Z<-\dfrac{3}{2})=\operatorname{pnorm}\left(-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)= 0.0668$

(c) To find $c$ in the past I was given a function which I don't have in this case.
Any ideas what I need to use to solve for $c$. Is it the Central Limit Theorem formula?

Answer (score 0):

You have $\displaystyle \bar X \sim N\left( 20, \left(\frac 2 3 \right)^2 \right)$ approximately. (Here you may have been slightly misled. Is this a reasonably close approximation?  An answer to that would have to rely on information beyond what is specified in the problem.  For some highly skewed distributions, $144$ would be nowhere near a big enough sample to warrant that conclusion; for more commonplace distributions $10$ is big enough for practical purposes.)  You need
$$
\Pr\left( \left|\frac{\bar X - 20}{2/3}\right| < \frac c {2/3} \right) = 0.95.
$$
$$
\Pr\left( |Z| < \frac 3 2 c \right) = 0.95\quad\text{where } Z \sim N(0,1).
$$
$$
\frac 3 2 c \approx 1.96.
$$
$$c\approx 1.31$$

Comment: we were given that if $N\geq 35$ we could use $\bar{X}\overset{approx}{\sim} N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ hence my approximation result for (a). Why are you taking the variance square

Comment: @Josesoriano : The variance is $(2/3)^2 = 4/9$. In the notation $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ the second argument is the variance, but I wanted to emphasize the value of the standard deviation, so I wrote $(2/3)^2$ instead of $4/9$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry I just want to be clear about this, if the problem gives us $\sigma^2 = 64$ When we do the approximate value of $\bar{X}$ we use $(\frac{64}{144})^2$ for the variance?

Comment: No; you have $\operatorname{var}(\bar X) = \dfrac{64}{144} = \left( \dfrac 8 {12} \right)^2$ (and $64/144$ reduces to $4/9$ and $8/12$ reduces to $2/3$).  And that is exact.  What is approximate is that it has a normal distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you I get it now. One last question, did the $\frac{3}{2}c$ came out as $\frac{2}{3}c$ due to the inequality changing directions?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I've fixed it.